# What does function in function do exactly in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

See this example:

```
var tools1 = require('../tools/tools1');
var test_func = function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {

    var local_var_1 = "lc1";
    var local_var_2 = "lc2";

    return function(data) {
    var result = tools1.doSth(local_var_1);
        result = result+local_var_2;
    }
}

exports.test_func = test_func;
```

I do not understand what does inner function do what it is for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript when you return function it returns reference of that function and you can call it later.

In your Code when you do `var result = test_func()`, `result` will hold reference of that function. Then later you can call that returned function like `result(data)`.

---

A basic example:

```js
function sum(x, y) {
  var rs = x+y;
  return function(message) {
    console.log(message + rs); //rs holds its value because of clousers
  }
}

var result = sum(2, 3);
result("This is result: ");
```

> Variables that are used locally, but defined in an enclosing scope
>   like `rs` in above example because of [**Closures**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it. You mean instead of getting an object or string or ... from a function as its output, we can get a function as output. right!?

Comment: Yes you can return a function. As i already mentioned we are actually returning **Reference**.

Answer (score 2):

This concept of function inside a function is known as closure in JavaScript. They are self invoking and makes it possible to have a function's private variables.
I am representing a similiar code of yours which I found in [W3schools.com](http://w3schools.com).

```
var add = (function () { 
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
})();

add();

add();

add();
```

Initially, the counter is set to 0 and then it returns a function reference. The counter is protected by the scope of the anonymous function, and can only be changed using the add() function.
The counter is set to 3 then, as add() function is called three times.

In the very similiar way, your code is working I guess:

```
var test_func = function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {

    var local_var_1 = "lc1";
    var local_var_2 = "lc2";

    return function(data) {
    var result = tools1.doSth(local_var_1);
        result = result+local_var_2;
    }
}
```

the local_var_1 and local_var_2 is set to "lc1' and "lc2" and returning a function reference.
The inner function then comes and do some operation with tools1.doSth() on local_var_1 and append the result with local_var_2.

Note: I am not clear with the output of your code, so I tried to tell you the steps with help of another code.